# When the modal is closed go to previous url in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, modal-dialog

Having a modal which is rendered when a conditions is fulfilled:

```
return this.state.value ? (
  <Modal> ... </Modal>
  ) : ( <div> ... </div>);
```

before the modal is opened the URL is like this: `http://myurl.com/items/5ed0c10ce1e24922e4906931`, after it is opened it adds a word 'edit' :

`http:///myurl.com/products/edit/5ed0c10ce1e24922e4906931`

The problem is when I close the modal it remain the longer URL, it doesn't revert to the initial one as it should.

I guess it must be added something in closeModal but don't know what. At the moment there is set `open` to false (which is set on true while the modal is visible)

```
  closeModal = () => {
    this.setState({ open: false });
  };
```

is there a way to get to the previous URL when the modal is closed?

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use `history.goBack()` method from react-router-dom.

Comment: how should `history` be declared?

Comment: `import {withRouter} from 'react-router-dom';`

`export withRouter(YourClass)` and `this.props.history.goBack()` in `YourClass`

Comment: If you are using `react-router-dom` this should already be working but I assume you don't. So  `window.history.back();` would also work as this is pure javascript. I would definitely recommend you to use react-router though.